# bigfoot with "para" option cannot count footnotes perpage

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

I'm typesetting a large and complex document with some tens of thousands of footnotes. Some of these notes are substantial, while many others are very short.

So I need to use footnote numbering "per page", which the `perpage` package handles fine.

I would also like to place the short notes inside a single paragraph where this is convenient, while the longer footnotes have their own paragraph. The `bigfoot` package with `\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}` does this nicely.

However I struggled to get the two behaviours to work together: when the paragraphing of notes is correct, it will not count footnotes per page.

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}

\begin{document}
Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an easy job with `\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}`. Do you like it?

Comment: Thanks Harsh. This doesn't quite work, as it places all the notes in one paragraph: I realize that my original request was not explicit enough and will modify it. What I want is the short notes in one para, with the long notes in their own paras, which is what `bigfoot` does. But the trick of adding `perpage` to the `footmisc` package does indeed work, I was already using that package for formatting but didn't realize it would do the `perpage` thing. So what worked was:    
    `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{bigfoot}
    \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}`

Answer (score 2):

The solution was following a modified version of Harish's suggestion:

```
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}


\usepackage{bigfoot}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\RestyleFootnote{default}{para}}
```

I am using `\AtBeginDocument` etc., rather than the original `\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}` following the suggestion of the package's author [in his comments on the package.](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91kastrup-bigfoot.pdf) However for my purposes both work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best idea to let other packages handle things that `bigfoot` does well on its own: you always have some risk that they might interfere with `bigfoot`.

`footmisc` might these days use `perpage` itself, so the accepted answer may well work.

At any rate, your problem seems entirely self-made: your MWE loads `perpage` without actually doing anything with it (`perpage` only provides facilities for changing counters in general but does not touch any existing counters).  The `bigfoot.dtx` file itself contains some minimal example of using `perpage` properly I think.

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP: In the OP's example, `\MakePerPage{footnotedefault}` needs to be added.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
\MakePerPage{footnotedefault}

\begin{document}
Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Short.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} Here is some paragraph text.\footnote{Here is quite a long, really very quite long, long footnote. It's actually very long if you take the time to read the whole thing.} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you elaborate a little bit on your answer, providing some example?